# Get xml node values by name attribute in php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, nodes

Here is my xml:

```
<student>
    <id>ah6d</id>
    <str name="filename">abc</str>
    <str name="format">doc</str>
    <str name="author">John</str>
    <int name="age">25</int>
    <int name="point">4</int>
    </student>

    <student>
    <id>fdsf</id>
    <str name="filename">efg</str>
    <str name="format">doc</str>
    <str name="author">Mary</str>
    <int name="age">23</int>
    <int name="point">3</int>
    </student>
```

...

I'd like to put the values into a mysql "students" table. Please help. I dont know how SimpleXMl works.

I tried...:

```
$lmx = file_get_contents("students.xml");
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($lmx);


foreach($xml as $student) {
$id=$student->id   ;
$filename=(string) @$xml->xpath('//student/str[@name="filename"]')[0];
$author=(string) @$xml->xpath('//student/str[@name="author"]')[0];
$age=(string) @$xml->xpath('//student/int[@name="age"]')[0];

 echo $id ."<br>";
 echo $filename ."<br>";
 echo $author ."<br>";
 echo $age ."<br>";

}
```

but it drops "Undefined offset: 0 "

Comment: Did you try something/search something?

Comment: Yes, i did. Thats why i am here. :(

Comment: If you did try something, add the code to you tried to the question

Comment: OK, here it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that your XML file is not valid. XML should be wrapped in 1 root element.

Here is an example:

```
$lmx = <<<END
<xml>
<student>
    <id>ah6d</id>
    <str name="filename">abc</str>
    <str name="format">doc</str>
    <str name="author">John</str>
    <int name="age">25</int>
    <int name="point">4</int>
</student>
<student>
    <id>fdsf</id>
    <str name="filename">efg</str>
    <str name="format">doc</str>
    <str name="author">Mary</str>
    <int name="age">23</int>
    <int name="point">3</int>
</student>
</xml>
END;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($lmx);


foreach($xml as $student) {
    $id = $student->id  ;
    $filename = (string) $xml->xpath('//student/str[@name="filename"]')[0];
    $author = (string) $xml->xpath('//student/str[@name="author"]')[0];
    $age = (string) $xml->xpath('//student/int[@name="age"]')[0];

    echo $id ."<br>\n";
    echo $filename ."<br>\n";
    echo $author ."<br>\n";
    echo $age ."<br>\n";

    echo "<br>\n<br>\n";
}
```

> Note that I wrapped the entire content with `<xml>...</xml>`

The output here will be:

```
ah6d<br>
abc<br>
John<br>
25<br>
<br>
<br>
fdsf<br>
abc<br>
John<br>
25<br>
<br>
<br>
```

If the content you get is in this exact structure (and you can't control it) what you can do is take that content and add the `root` xml element to the string.

Here is an example for how you can wrap the string:

```
$lmx = "<xml>" . file_get_contents("students.xml") . "</xml>";
```

Comment: You're right! Thanks! But why does the outoutput have the first students data two times? It can be, that the loop is wrong? or why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "output have the first students data two times". I see it only one time.

Comment: You posted it:
ah6d<br>
abc<br>
John<br>
25<br>
<br>
<br>
fdsf<br>
abc<br>
John<br>
25<br>
<br>
<br>

Its the same.

Comment: Oh :) thats because you always get the  `$xml->xpath('//student/str[@name="filename"]')[0]`, regardless the **current** `student` :)

Comment: I see. Thanks! :)